# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable, discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.bot(command_prefix = ".")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm in!")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
    if message.author == client.user:
       return
    
    if message.content.startswith("hello"):
        await message.channel.send('hello!')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("someone's here!")


@client.event
async def on_typing(channel, user, when):
    print("Lol, someone is typing!!1!")

@client.command()
async def answer(ans):
    await ans.send("Here is your answer")
```

error:

File "/Users/me/documents/bot/bot.py", line 5, in 
client = commands.bot(command_prefix = ".")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Do i have to install anything else as discord.py?

Comment: `commands.bot` is a module; it is not a callable function.

Comment: I believe you made a typo. Have you tried `commands.Bot`? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind lower/upper cases! `commands.bot` is a module indeed https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/bot.py

`commands.bot.Bot` is the callable object. Since you have imported `Bot` already, just use that.

```
client = Bot(command_prefix = ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

When Importing Moduals, You Might Need To Include The Module Prefix.

```
client = discord.commands.bot(command_prefix = ".")
```

If This doesn't work, I can't help. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo, you need to use `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")`.